# Where to put JSON file with API key for Private Access

Tags: c#, .net, iis, asmx

I have a web application (asmx) which uses API secret stored in a JSON file.Currently i have put the file in wwwroot/myapp/ folder

```
        string htmlFilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/");
        string contents = File.ReadAllText(htmlFilePath+@"\file.json");
        return contents;
```

This file is publicly accessable from the browser.How can make this file only accessable by the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new folder called, App_Data in your web project and drop your private files there. By default, ASP will forbid the files inside App_Data folder for public access.

Comment: I have created the `App_Data` folder and put the file there.I keep getting a File not found exception `string htmlFilePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            string contents = File.ReadAllText(htmlFilePath+@"\file.json");`

Comment: Mention real path for the file.

Comment: HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data")

Answer (score 0):

Within the configuration of IIS, you can employ filtering in order to deny access to resources on your server. If I'm right, the `<denyUrlSequences>` configuration element could be suitable

> The `<denyUrlSequences>` element contains a collection of  elements that specify sequences of URL characters that IIS will deny, which helps prevent URL-based attacks on the Web server.

In your IIS configuration use the following to filter your `privatekey.json`

```xml
<system.webServer>
   <security>
      <requestFiltering>
         <denyUrlSequences>
            <add sequence="privatekey.json" />
         </denyUrlSequences>
      </requestFiltering>
   </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Otherwise, you could store the file out of the root of IIS, e.g. `C:\.private\privatekey.json` and load the file from there.